# Merging .csv files in query to retrieve its data from Excel through a UDF and ADODB connection

Tags: excel, vba, csv, select, merge

My goal is to run some code in `vba` and call the function from an Excel cell to retrieve some data from a closed `.csv` file or `.xlsx` file.

This could be done in several ways, but all I've tried have an important constraint.

I start with a very large `.csv` file. Very large is around 4,000 rows and more than 1,000 columns.

**First try:**

Save the `.csv` in an Excel worksheet and use `ExecuteExcel4Macro` to retrieve the data. This works fine when running a `Sub`, and even when running a `Function`. But, unfortunately, you can't use `ExecuteExcel4Macro` and call it from an Excel cell. The first try is done.

**Second try**

Use an `ADODB Connection` and run a query directly from the `.csv` file or from the saved `.xlsx` file. This can be used from a cell, but, surprise, surprise, it has a limit of 255 columns or fields. I mean, when you run a query and try to read a field that is positioned in a column number greater than 255, the function does nothing. Second try done.

**Third (and last (by now)) try. Need your help here!**

Ok, I could divide the original table, which has too many fields into several tables containing a maximum of 255 fields each.

Note: the first column contains the ids of firms, banks or whatever. The rest of the fields are named x1, x2,...x1050 and they correspond to fields of financial statements, so they are all numeric and they are all useful for the analysis.

If I split the big table in different ones, the aspect would be like:

```
Table 1:
Name     x1     x2     x5    x6    x15...
myName1  15025  1546   6546  548   98663
myName2  867486 4684   68786 876   68997
myName3  87663  43397  87987 457   -4554
etc.

...

Table n:
Name     x928     x929     x940    x1005    x1250
myName1  765454   541546   76546   74548    18663
myName2  6564     544684   686     41876    58997
myName3  4687     64397    9887    879457   8554
```

I can do this by running some vba before I store the files, so now I have `n` `.csv` files. The point is that I want the formula called from a cell like this:

```
=GetData(path,file,name,operations)
```

I mean, the user wants to locate a `name` in a `file` and make some `operations` with "all" the fiels available, from 1 to 1250.

Let's suposse the first splitted table goes from x1 field to x250 field. The second would go from x251 to x500, etc. All of the tables would have a first column with the `names` field, of course, and all tables would have the same number of rows (not the same number of columns, as not all x's fields exist).

But, important, the `operations` called by user could be like:

```
"x3"                      --> User requests only one field.
"x5+x150"                 --> User requests the sum of two fields that would be in the same table (as the x150 field is not greater than x250 field)
"x452+x535-x900+x1200-x1" --> User requests operations with many fields that would be kept in different files.
```

When the user requests only a field, I can write a small routine in the beggining of the function to tell the function in which `.csv` file is that field stored, like:

```
if singleField<=250 then 
  fileToLookAt="SplittedCSV_1"
end if 
if singleField>250 and singleField<=500 then 
  fileToLookAt="SplittedCSV_2"
end if
```

Then, using an `ADODB Connection` and `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` provider, I would run the query like:

```
MyQuery = "SELECT x" & singleField & " AS MyData FROM [" & fileToLookAt & ".csv] WHERE Name='" & name & "'"
```

But, what happens when the user wants an operation involving x's fields stored in all different files, like the third example I gave? I would have to "merge" all tables, using `Name` field as the key for merging then.

How would you proceed? Is it merging the tables in the `Select` the best option? How would the `Select` be?

I mean the Query would be like:

```
MyQuery = "SELECT x452+x535-x900+x1200-x1 AS MyData FROM [" & MergedTable & ".csv] WHERE Name='" & name & "'"
```

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *"run it from an Excel cell"*.

Comment: I mean to call the function from a cell: `=GetData(path,file,name,operations)`

Comment: Why do you want do so? You read the data once, right? After that, you want to query it multiple times? Have you thought about putting the data into a real database where you don't have the 255 field limitation?

Comment: I can put it in a database, but users must use Excel to retrieve the data point they want.

Comment: How does the user tells the program what he wants?

Comment: Users can still use Excel as a front end but have the data sitting in a database in the back end

Comment: Sure, but you wrote *"the operations called by user could be like"* - how tells the user which operations he want?

Comment: @Zac All Excel connections I know to databases or csv files or even names or ranges to another Excel workbook have the limit of 255 columns. Do you know any ADODB provider that doesn't have this limit?

Comment: @FunThomas The operations is a string parameter in the function. As I said, it can be "x1+x5-x873" or whatever

Comment: Sql Server ado connection supports 4K columns for a SELECT statement

Comment: Why would you ever want 255 (or more) columns in a table? It's a database. You can design it so that you have multiple tables for multitude of reasons. You might have 1k columns coming in your `csv` file, but you add them to relevant tables.. maybe I'm missing something

Comment: @Zac Please read the question carefully. The users may want to access to each of the (1,000) fields or to a sum of some of them. So there's nothing like "relevant" or "non-relevant" fields.

Comment: @Javi: I believe I've missed a point here. I don't see an issue using this in a database but don't want to waste OP's time. OP, please ignore my comments because I must be missing something

Answer (score 1):

You could stuff the data into a mdb file using ado and bypass the 256 column limitation. However, using UDF's to retrieve data directly from any external datasource is going to be very slow if you have more than a few. I would create a class to hold the data, with a load method called on opening the spreadsheet, and have your functions query the object. So your load method takes your csv as a datastream and fills a disconected ado recordset defined as a static variable, and then you define a getdata method that returns your desired value based on the parameters passed to it.

Comment: Can you elaborate your answer more? Maybe some code?